# sql merging 2 tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `products` and `products_description`. I want these fields from `products`: `products_id`, `products_quantity`, `products_model`, `products_image` and `products_price`.

I would like to join that with the field `products_description` from `products_description`

The SQL I have so far is

```
SELECT products.products_id, products.products_quantity, products.products_image, products.products_price, products_image
 FROM products
 INNER JOIN products_description
 ON products.products_id=products_description.products_id
 ORDER BY products.products_id
```

My results were just field names taken from the products table and nothing from
the `products_description` table. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN` is correct, but you didn't *select* anything from the `products_description` table.

Update your `SELECT` to include columns from `products_description` (substitute the proper column names).

```
SELECT products.products_id, ..., products_description.column_name, products_description.column_name2, ...
```

Comment: where would i put that in my statement-sql

Comment: i am getting an error using phpmy admin it says error 1142 denied use of table which is weird becasue i can view the table

Comment: That's a separate issue. Likely dealing with access/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write `products_description.*` (which will get all columns from products_description table) in your SELECT statement.

```
SELECT products.products_id, products.products_quantity, products.products_image, products.products_price, products_image, products_description.*
 FROM products
 INNER JOIN products_description
 ON products.products_id=products_description.products_id
 ORDER BY products.products_id
```

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin and getting an error 1142 it says i am denied

Comment: Execute this.. `GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`.. update password, database and username as yours